# Passing parameters to UsingFactoryMethod in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

How do I pass dynamic parameters to a `UsingFactoryMethod` registration?

For example, I want to write something like:

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<IFoo>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(return DoSomethingAndReturnInstance(paremeter)));
```

I need the parameters to be sent at runtime, like this:

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>(new { parameter = value });
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CreationContext.AdditionalParameters` has the values you pass to `Resolve`

Comment: Can you give an example usage, based on the question above?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFoo>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, creationContext) =>
        {
            var parameter = creationContext.AdditionalArguments["parameter"];
            return DoSomethingAndReturnInstance(parameter);
        }));
```